# Extract one tag out of many from HTML source (using Java)

Tags: java, android, html

In the string:

```
    "<span >x </span><span >y</span> <span >z</span>"
```

I want to extract the data within the third `<span>` tag ie "z". How can I directly refer to third one?

```
    import org.jsoup.*;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

    String str = "  <span >x </span>  <span >y</span>   <span>  z   </span>  ";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
    Elements link = doc.getElementsByTag("span");

    for (Element link2 : link)
    {
        p= link.text();
    }
```

Comment: is that javascript? I've never seen such a weird code.

Comment: Please edit your code appropriately; I've made it look like what I think you mean. Without knowing what library/etc. you're using we're just guessing--please ask accurate and complete questions :)

Comment: If it's javascript, just give the span in question an id and fetch its content using the id

Comment: @SahilManchanda Keyser is saying you should add IDs to the html.

Comment: Man, I hope your code is indented better than that in real life.

Comment: its not my code. im using data frOM a website

Answer (score 0):

To find the third instance of a String in Java, try something simple like this:

```
String key = "<span >";
int index = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    index = str.indexOf(key, index + key.length());
}

if(index > -1) {
    // Found it
    String result = str.substring(index, str.indexOf("</span>", index + key.length()));
}
```

Also if there are only three `<span >` elements you can simply use:

```
index = str.lastIndexOf(key);
```

Comment: but i need the data inside that. shall i start on index and end upon where i find the </span>

Comment: Check [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using JSoup. I am not familiar with this, but since the documentation says it is similar to jQuery, I would guess something like `doc.select('parent_element_selector').find('span').get(0)`.

I believe [this](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) is what you want.